# Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname) is taking 20 seconds time to load the next page

Tags: asp.net, dns

In my ASP.Net Default Page i am providing the credentials, and i used the code "Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)" to get the Machine Name. But it is taking 19+ seconds to load the next page.

```
var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(clientIP);
    return hostEntry.HostName;
```

Can any one help on this to get the machine name very fast?

Comment: please have a look at the similar thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997046/gethostentry-is-very-slow

Comment: tried but i am getting only Clients IP address, but not the machine name. How do get the machine name? Is there any alternative way for Dns.GetHostEntry to retrieve the machine name?

Answer (score 0):

use `.ToString()` when handover an IPAddress it results in a speedboost.

Example:

```
IPHostEntry hostinfo = Dns.GetHostEntry( data.ToString() )
```

Doesn't matter if the data is a Hostname (string) or an IPAddress like x.x.x.x.

If no one else has this feeling then something is wrong with the network I am connected to.